# Driver call Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, driver

Can a driver call a C# web service or any other language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically yes it can. Its just a call via the protocol that the service is using. However since you're in kernel mode, certain USER mode libraries may not be available to you so you may have to code around these yourself.

For example if the service is running on a HTTP endpoint, then you can use raw sockets to access this.

How difficult this is depends on the platform the driver is in.